# Updating one table using values from multiple other tables

Tags: mysql, updates

I've gotten better at Updates and Joins but this problem seems to be stumping me. I hope I've explained it clearly below, forgive the field/table notations but I've tried to keep them so that once I have an answer I can easily apply to my actual situation. Any clarifications that are needed I am happy to provide, I've tried to keep it both explanatory and simple, hopefully I succeeded.

I am trying to update Table_J B_ID field which me to look up both `C` and `X_ID` values in that record:

**Table_J:**

```
+----+-------+------+------+
| ID | C     | X_ID | B_ID |
+----+-------+------+------+
| 1  | Alpha | 10   |      |
+----+-------+------+------+
| 2  | Alpha | 20   |      |
+----+-------+------+------+
| 3  | Alpha | 30   |      |
+----+-------+------+------+
| 4  | Beta  | 50   |      |
+----+-------+------+------+
```

in other tables.

First, for each record I need to find all the B_ID values for records in Table_C that match `C` in Table_J:

**Table_C:**

```
+-------+------+
| C     | B_ID |
+-------+------+
| Alpha | 100  |
+-------+------+
| Alpha | 200  |
+-------+------+
| Alpha | 300  |
+-------+------+
| Beta  | 400  |
+-------+------+
| Beta  | 500  |
+-------+------+
```

In the case of Record 1 in Table_J where `C` = `Alpha` in this case I'd have `B_ID` values of `100`, `200` and `300` from `Table_C`

I then need to find the records in Table_X where `B_ID` equals any of those found values AND the `X_ID` of Record 1 in Table_J which is `10` and Update `B_ID` in Table_J with the `B_ID` found in `Table_X`, in this case `100`.

**Table_X:**

```
+------+------+
| B_ID | X_ID |
+------+------+
| 100  | 10   |
+------+------+
| 200  | 20   |
+------+------+
| 300  | 30   |
+------+------+
| 400  | 40   |
+------+------+
| 500  | 50   |
+------+------+
| 600  | 10   |
+------+------+
| 700  | 20   |
+------+------+
| 800  | 30   |
+------+------+
| 900  | 10   |
+------+------+
```

After the final update `Table_J` would update like so:

**Table J Updated:**

```
+----+-------+------+------+
| ID | C     | X_ID | B_ID |
+----+-------+------+------+
| 1  | Alpha | 10   | 100  |
+----+-------+------+------+
| 2  | Alpha | 20   | 200  |
+----+-------+------+------+
| 3  | Alpha | 30   | 300  |
+----+-------+------+------+
| 4  | Beta  | 50   | 50   |
+----+-------+------+------+
```

Comment: Because Table J has a _new_ record in it, you are not strictly doing an `UPDATE`.  Rather, you are doing a complex series of updates and inserts.  Please clarify where the extra `Beta` record is coming from in your expected output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen A mistake on my part creating the tables, fixed the issue with an edit so the original Table_J has the same # of records. Definitely is NOT an insert question just update.

Comment: Your join condition going from `Table_J` to `Table_C` does not make sense.  An inner join would produce 9 records, not 3.  You need to rethink your logic.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Not sure where you get that. Record 1 in Table_J searches for 'Alpha' in Table_C. Finds 3 records (B_ID 100,200 and 300). In turn those find 3 records in Table_X only one has an X_ID of 10 which matches Record 1 in Table_J not 9.  I haven't yet applied logic/solution just the tables and am trying now to figure out how to get the end result.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Also even with 9 records in the second stage join (if that is what the solution is) only 1 of those will match Table_X for the update. So if the inner join in fact has each of 10,20,30 mapped to each of 100,200,300 for 9 records, only 3 of those will be the correct match in Table_X (10/100, 20/200, 30/300).

Comment: Please review how join works in a relational database.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen There is nothing for me to review. I did not suggest a Join or an Inner Join. I asked: given the data in the tables how can I construct an update to get the necessary data. If you are unable to answer or help that is fine as well.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen As somehow the joins on this relational database work perfectly with `Update J as T1
Inner Join C T2 Inner Join X T3
On T3.X_ID=T1.X_ID and T3.B_ID=T2.B_ID and T1.C=T2.C
Set T1.B_ID=T3.B_ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Update J as T1
Inner Join C T2 Inner Join X T3
On T3.X_ID=T1.X_ID 
and T3.B_ID=T2.B_ID 
and T1.C=T2.C
Set T1.B_ID=T3.B_ID
```

It turned out to be simpler than I thought;

- first naturally I needed to Join all three tables.
- The `Set` is what I am ultimately looking for and in this case updating `Table_J` with the correct `B_ID` from `Table_X`
- And the meat of it is the `On`:
- The `X_ID` from `Table_J` (the update table) had to match the `X_ID` from `Table_X`
- while the `B_ID` from `Table_C` had to match the `B_ID` from `Table_X` (the intermediary table)
- and connecting those two conditions the `C` from `Table_J` had to match the `C` from `Table_C`.

The issue of course is that there can be multiple B_IDs associated with X_IDs in Table_X and there can be multiple B_IDs associated with C in Table C.  Given that in Table_J I know C and X_ID the first join allows me to gather all of the B_IDs associated with C and then the last join allows me to find which of those B_IDs have the same X_ID from the Table_J record.

Edit: I realize this could be confusing, I made  Sql Fiddle here to demonstrate: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd23c3/2. I could only do it as Select but the concept is the same.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk Done, with SqlFiddle as well.